# Android scroll two webview at the same time

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am very new to Android,and my situation is I got webview1 and webview2 on the same Activity,and switch them by button. 
And I have no idea to do this 
 1. I scroll webview1 and webview2 scroll automatically. 
 2. webview1 and webview2 will scroll to end at the same time

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView myWebView,myWebView2;
int webTextDefault = 100;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(myWebView1);
    //myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/try1.html");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    myWebView2 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView2);
    myWebView2.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    myWebView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    myWebView2.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/try2.html");
    myWebView2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


}



public void myClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button:
            myWebView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            myWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            myWebView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            myWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You could use one webview with two divs (or frames) inside it, each one of them showing one html, then scroll'em together.

Comment: Thank you for advise . i want to try your way . Is there more information for me to read?